# Validating cloudFormation templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, validation, error-handling, yaml

Is it possible to validate the syntax of cloudFormation templates locally before uploading them to AWS?

I know terraform has the command: `terraform validate`, which is used to confirm whether or not there are any syntactical errors within your Terraform configuration files.

Can the same be achieved with cloudFormation?

I am currently uploading a cloudFormation template stored locally to s3 and wanted to locally validate the template so as to avoid re-uploading after attempting a fix to the following error:  `Template format error: DependsOn must be a string or list of strings.`

I am using Visual Studio Code IDE and could not find any extension that validates the syntax of cloudFormation templates.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about `aws cloudformation validate-template`?

Comment: You may take a look at the following:
https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-lint
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/validate-template.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2YGpAWjuW8